# Find functions $f_k(x)$ that converge to $1$ point-wise, complying with conditions

Tags: real-analysis, pointwise-convergence

I'm looking for continuous function $f_k(x), \forall x\in[0,1]$ which are $C^N$ for $x\in(0,1)$ with given $N>0$, complying with this conditions:

- $f_k(x)>0, \forall x\in(0,1)$
- $f_k(0) = 0$
- $f_k(1) = 1$
- $f_k^{(i)}(0) = f_k^{(i)}(1) =  0, i=1,\dots,N$.

Finally, the goal is to construct these functions such that

$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} f_k(x) = 1, \forall x\in(0,1)
$$

Inspired by the classical example of $x^{1/k}$, which complies $x^{1/k}\to 1$ as $k\to \infty, \forall x\in(0,1)$ I've been playing around with polynomials, fractional powers and combinations of these. However, I have only managed to comply the boundary conditions, but not succeed with the convergence part. I'm starting to suspect that this is not possible due to the flatness conditions at $x=0$ and $x=1$.

If its not possible, what is the closest we can get?

Comment: This is possible, even with $N=+\infty$. Try to play with the function $g$ defined by $g(x)=0$ if $x \leq 0$ and $g(x)=\exp(-1/x)$ if $x > 0$. Can you prove that $g$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ and that $g^{(n)}(0)=0$ for every $n$ ?

Comment: Oh yeah! I know that function. But what about the behavior at $x=1$? even if I make $g(x)$ "spiky" by playing with the argument, the non-flatness at $x=1$ do not disappear? I'll keep playing with it anyway. Thanks sir!

Comment: You can combine several such functions to get what you want. For example, the function $$h : x\mapsto \frac{g(x)}{g(x)+g(1-x)}$$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ and satisfies $h(x)=0$ if $x \leq 0$ and $h(x)=1$ if $x \geq 1$. Now by playing with the argument, you will be able to make the function "increase earlier and earlier" to get what you want.

Comment: Hmm, very interesting. Let me play with that. Thanks!